# Macro Enable Workbook is creating new file with SaveAsUI instead of saving itself

Tags: excel, vba

I call the below line to save my workbook from another file:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

This code needs to be and run in a different file than the one I have open and active.

When this code runs from another workbook, the file that I have open and active calls the SaveAsUI to save the file again, even if already saved.

After running the code above, the original workbook is lost. I cannot save the active workbook anymore, manually or by macros, and I don't want to save as my original file. Several errors occur, such as:

Random filename in the SaveAsUI
[image]

Unexpected Error, AutoRecover Disabled
[image]

Share Rule Violation (PT/BR)
[image]

I cannot catch this error in English. Here its translation:

> Your changes could not be saved in 'File' due to a sharing violation. Try saving to another file.

This error started after I enabled auto-save. I don't know if it is something related to the cloud and Excel gets lost when saving.
Also, saving the original file outside the network the problem did not appear3

PS: The workbook with I have enabled AutoSave has nothing to do with those that are giving error. That was a workbook without macros for a much simpler project.

Comment: Just a long shot at helping... In Office365 Excel with Sharepoint synced files, I have had a "cannot open two files with same name" error if I change the file name in Windows (and not in the Name bar at the top of excel) and then copy, rename and open the file. Which shows some weird glitch is happening currently for me. Try renaming your files to something else and then back again, using the excel NAME BAR.

Comment: The workbook that is giving the error never had AutoSave turned on, unfortunately I don't think this is the case. Of course, only if there is a weird glitch going on. But I had no results with that, I tried renaming but no success.

Comment: I don't know if this applies to you, our documents are synched to sharepoint using/through Onedrive... this results in 3 ways to access the documents...1, through the "Company" folder. 2, through the "OneDrive" folder, and 3, through C Drive/Users. I have found for saving that only the Local C Drive option is reliable. Things to check: are you opening both files though a "local" method. Try fully qualifying the file instead of using ActiveWorkbook. What does Debug.Print say about your save strings.

Comment: This is not the case, all the files that are having this problem have never been shared. They are only saved as standard .xlsm files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find what was causing the problem. I initially thought it was the VBA macro part and the "ActiveWorkbook.save" command, but in the end the problem was much deeper.

It turns out that in the same macro that contained the save command there was a call to another function that updated the queries.

**the error would stop when going into PowerQuery Editor, going into the spreadsheet query that would later give the share violation error, and in the steps remove the action of promoting the headers.**

I have no idea why this is the error. But I tried several other ways in several other places (like every tip in this [link1](https://excelinexcel.in/ms-excel/formulas/sharing-violation/), or this [link2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/refreshing-powerquery-in-a-shared-excel-workbook/c219ae45-7982-47f1-9a72-0491601c5ebb), or this [link3](https://windowsreport.com/excel-sharing-violation-error/)), the only way that resulted in the solution was this above (that I don't find in any place).

But the promotion of the headers is necessary, so to continue without giving problems I needed to go into the advanced editor and change the second parameter of the line below from "null" to "true" (which is basically to promote headers at the query stage).

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(FilePath), true, true),
```

With this, everthing now is working fine.